# Is there function in pytorch similar to tf.contrib.distributions.percentile of tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

Is there a function in PyTorch that does the same as [`tf.contrib.distributions.percentile`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/distributions/percentile) of Tensorflow?

Comment: The question says nothing about what exactly you want to achieve. Is it a percentile over a standard distribution (e.g. normal/laplace) or over an array? Will it be used during deep learning or not? (deep learning depends heavily on derivatives which is hard with percentiles, and e.g. generalized mean or smooth maximum should be used instead as approximation of percentiles)

Answer (score 4):

Interestingly, it seems PyTorch is not providing any operator on its own for this, at least not according to [its search function](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/search.html?q=percentile&check_keywords=yes&area=default#).
Fortunately, though, PyTorch Tensors can easily be used with NumPy functions, so that you can simply call `numpy.percentile`, see the example below:

```
import torch as t
import numpy as np

x = t.Tensor([1,2,3])
print(np.percentile(x, 30)) # 30-th percentile of x
# 1.6
```

Comment: Thank you vary much. I think that your answer solves my problem in one way. But using numpy will have some trouble when Tensor has already been parallel to cuda.

Comment: That is a very good point! I unfortunately do not have access to Pytorch with CUDA, but from what I have been reading online, this is indeed not possible to do without (a) gathering the results from GPU back to CPU, or (b) writing custom CUDA operators. Also keep in mind that the overhead of GPU initialization takes quite a lot of time in itself, so unless you are working with insanely large tensors, it might be (almost as) efficient to use method (a)

Answer (score 4):

It has been a while since PyTorch introduced [its own implementation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.quantile.html) of the quantile similar to `numpy.quantile`, which is essentially [analogous to the percentile](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/156778/percentile-vs-quantile-vs-quartile) but with decimal values instead of hundredths.

For instance, you can compute the 50th percentile of a tensor as follows:

```py
import torch

x = torch.tensor([1., 2., 3., 4., 5.])
print(torch.quantile(x, 0.5)) # 50-th percentile
# tensor(3.)
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually the `icdf` function gives the inverse cumulative density function value, which is the value for the percentile.

```
import torch
from torch.distributions import Normal
dist = Normal(torch.tensor([0.0]), torch.tensor([1.0]))
dist.icdf(torch.tensor([0.95])).data.numpy()
```

results in

```
array([1.6449], dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know the pro and con, 
but there is method to use cupy with pytorch dlpack:

(cupy doesn't support pytorch tensor directly, CuPy functions does not accept torch tensors.)

```
import torch
from torch.utils.dlpack import to_dlpack
from torch.utils.dlpack import from_dlpack
import cupy

x = torch.Tensor([1, 2, 3]).cuda()
dx = to_dlpack(x)
cx = cupy.fromDlpack(dx)
print(cupy.percentile(cx, 30)) # 30-th percentile of x
# 1.5999999642372131
```